# How to display the report icon in Firefox for the SQL Server Reporting Services Report Viewer control

Tags: sql-server, firefox, reporting-services

It seems that due to ActiveX that Firefox can't display the print icon/button on the Report Viewer control in SQL Server Reporting services.  Has anybody figured out a way to work around this or gotten this to work?

If it's not possible, does anybody know of a way to add a standard button that would trigger the print behavior on the report viewer control?

Comment: it is an old question did you over come this limitation.
do you have some answers now

Answer (score 1):

As you state, the print functionality is ActiveX, so it will not work in Firefox.

You could place a button in the "msrs-buttonHeaderBackground" div using a javascript button.

I found the div using the firebug firefox extension - it's great.

You could possibly find the other divs you'd like to hide and put them in a print style sheet, so they don't show up when going to print.

http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200709/how_to_create_an_unobtrusive_print_this_page_link_with_javascript/

I agree with the author that ctrl-p could simply be pressed for a similar result instead of adding a button - but the print style would still help in that.

You know what...I just realized something.  You will not be able to print a page that is more than one page!  Ouch.

Comment: Right, I would need to print the report in the report viewer's "print mode".  I am going to see if there's a way to tap into the report viewer's event and come up with a solution on my own.

Comment: I'd be interested to hear how this works out.  You are very brave :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old questions, but we came across this and chose the following solution.

We downloaded an [IE Tab extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ie-tab-2-ff-36/)(this is one there are several more) for FireFox and then configured that extension to use IE to render the report server URL by default.

You could easily create a how-to web page,pdf, or maybe even create a dummy report that shows the instructions on how to do this to your end users and then you're all set.

So now every time the report server website is accessed it's being rendered in IE so the print button shows up. Every windows machine already has IE so no compatibility issue there, unless you're not using windows. :)

Comment: Not really an option as some of our users use Mac.

Answer (score 0):

My best suggestion would be from within Firefox export it to PDF and then print it from your PDF viewer.  In my experience this is a better way to print the reports anyway.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That's what we tell our customers they can do as a work around.  Unfortunately, it's just that... a work around.